# should libgit2sharp Repository be explicitly disposed?

Tags: git, repository, dispose, using-statement, libgit2sharp

Should a libgit2sharp `Repository` object be explicitly disposed ?

If clean-up is not always performed via `Repository.Dispose()` , what are the possible negative consequences ?  Could a non-GC'd `Repository` object retain locks on various .git files ?

Is it best to wrap Repository object in `using` statement ?

```
var localRepo = new Repository("{local repo path}", new RepositoryOptions());
using (localRepo) {
    // checkout
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disposing a `Repository` is recommended practice.

Indeed, this type holds pointers to non managed resources (native memory, indirect pointers to file handles under the `.git` directory, ...).

`Dispose()` will make sure that those resources are properly freed/released.

However, some safety net has been implemented would the caller forget to do so. the `Repository` type defines a **[finalizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize)** which will take care of this.

Keep in mind that the moment this finalizer will run isn't predictable (as stated by the documentation *"before it is reclaimed by garbage collection"*).

Thus, the recommendation to control by yourself the disposal of your repository.

Comment: I don’t see the finalizer in the source code, am i missing something? I want to use LibGit2Sharp within a PowerShell script so I am not too worried if cleanup happens delayed when GC collects the object, as long as it runs _eventually_

Comment: @felixfbecker Finalizer is no longer needed. See commit **[3a7ec78](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/3a7ec7847fc7d7eab2f453f9f972c99918801b2f)**.

Comment: Interesting, could you explain what that safe handle does? Do you think it's okay to not dispose in PowerShell?

Comment: @felixfbecker I'm sure this would make an amazing StackOverflow question of its own. ;-)